# geometry errors

Tags: packages, geometry

I can't seem to get rid of these errors, sorry for the long preamble but I can't figure out what is causing it, have tried deleting some and it goes awaybut I need them all for my overall document. any help would be welcome.

```
\documentclass{book}

%-----------------------------Packages----------------------------%
\usepackage{geometry}           %Adjust page layout
\usepackage{parskip}                % Set zero paragraph indent and non-zero paragraph spacing
\usepackage{fancyhdr}               % Customize headers and footers
\usepackage{graphicx}               % Include graphics
\usepackage{setspace}               % Adjust line spacing
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % Input encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Font encoding
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}               % Better horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{xspace}                 % Used for printing a trailing space better than using a tilde (~) using the \xspace command
\usepackage{microtype}              % Improves character and word spacing
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}            %Boxes for headings or text
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titlesec}               % Customize chapter and section titles
\usepackage{sidenotes}              % For Tufte-style sidenotes
\usepackage{libertine}              % Use the Linux Libertine font
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{epigraph}
    \usepackage{environ}


\setstretch{1.5}                                % Adjust line spacing
\pagestyle{fancy}  
%%%%%%

\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
  \newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{\begingroup\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont#1\endgroup}%%%%%%Greek Writing

%%%%%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

% Wide margins
\geometry{
    paperwidth=170mm,
    paperheight=240mm,
    left=40mm,
    top=30mm,
    textwidth=95mm,
    marginparsep=8mm,
    marginparwidth=52mm,
    textheight=38\baselineskip,
    headsep=12mm,
}

% Margin citation
\usepackage{natbib}
%\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}

% Margin figures

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{marginfix} % To fix the margin figure placement
\usepackage{sidenotes} % For Tufte-style sidenotes
\usepackage{libertine} % Use the Linux Libertine font

% Set the head height and adjust the top margin
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em} % Remove paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parskip}{1em} % Set paragraph spacing

\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio} % Improves figure scaling

\begin{document}

A straight line originating from the vertex and pivoting within the plane of the angle, transitioning from alignment with one side to alignment with the other, is termed to have rotated through the angle. This angle increases proportionally with the degree of rotation. Additionally, considering that the line can rotate in two distinct directions between these positions, two angles emerge from lines drawn from a common point.

\end{document}
```

geometry error.tex

Package geometry Warning: `bmargin' results in NEGATIVE (-86.49213pt).` height' or `tmargin' should be shortened in length.
geometry error.tex

Package geometry Warning: `bmargin' results in NEGATIVE (-86.49213pt).` height' or `tmargin' should be shortened in length.

Comment: The default `\baselineskip` =18pt.  Your top(30mm)+textheight(`38\baselineskip`) is already greater than `\paperheight` (240mm).

Comment: As Tom said, you are overspecifying your paper geometry and asking for imposible layout

Comment: And then you creep sneakily behind `geometry`'s back and change `\headheight` while it isn't looking. If you don't want to use `geometry` don't. If you do, you must *always* use it to set stuff related to the page layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Loading `lmodern` and `libertine` (this one twice!) makes no sense.
2. You're lucky that `xcolor` has been recently updated so it can be loaded multiple times (because several packages load it, maybe with different options), but it's not a justification to do it yourself

   `\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}`
3. Same for loading `fontenc` multiple times

   `\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}`
4. I can't see how

   `\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio} % Improves figure scaling`

   can do what it advertises. Even a smallish picture will get as big as possible.

Avoid copying someone else's preamble and add to it (the double loading of `sidenotes` is a hint that it's the case). If that preamble is your own work, you really need to clean it up.

Now the real problem.

```
\geometry{
    paperwidth=170mm,
    paperheight=240mm,
    left=40mm,
    top=30mm,
    textwidth=95mm,
    marginparsep=8mm,
    marginparwidth=52mm,
    textheight=38\baselineskip,
    headsep=12mm,
}
```

to which we also should add `headheight=14.5pt`.

You seem to want 38 lines of text but also ask for `\setstretch{1.5}`. Now the standard baseline skip is 12pt, so you get 18pt and multiplying this by 38 gives 684pt, that is, a little more than 240mm. And you're asking for a paper that's 240mm high.

No way you can do it. With

```
\geometry{
    paperwidth=170mm,
    paperheight=240mm,
    left=40mm,
    top=30mm,
    textwidth=95mm,
    marginparsep=8mm,
    marginparwidth=52mm,
%    textheight=38\baselineskip,
    headsep=12mm,
    headheight=14.5pt,
    heightrounded,
}
```

(note `heightrounded`) we get 29 lines. Here's the picture (obtained by repeating the text you typed and removing `\usepackage{parskip}`) of pages 2 and 3, where you see that you're not reserving enough space for the margin notes, due to the big inner margin and large `\marginparwidth`. Something you need to take care of.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @egreg, it is my own work but just I have been working with multiple preambles for different sections of my work and just lumped them all in to one file for this question. But thanks I have trouble organising my preambles never sure which interact with what. I'll see what I can do about the margins but might end up posting another question.